# Cuda out of memory- Matrix multiplication

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication, attention-model

I am trying to run Stand-Alone-Self-Attention model.
Even with batch size=1, it complains CUDA out of memory because of out=key*query: https://github.com/leaderj1001/Stand-Alone-Self-Attention/blob/a983f0f643632b1f2b7b8b27693182f22e9e574c/attention.py#L48

The tensor of the key is [2,8,8,224,224,49]
The tensor of the query is [2,8,8,224,224,1]
The dim 1 is batch, dim 2 is self.groups, dim 3 is out_channels, dim 4 is height, dim 5 is width, and dim 6 = -1.

A very naive thought is to split these two matrixes into several blocks, like [split3D used for self-attention implemented in Keras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKQUd.png). But I am not sure how will it work in 6 dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution to this back then?